# Cloudfront Lambda@Edge Set-Cookie header doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have a CloudFront distribution which uses 2 Lambda@Edge functions at Viewer Request and Viewer Response.

In the app, there will be a first request which has a token at query string, and following series of requests which has the token at "cookie" header.

I validate the token from "querystring" at viewer request. After validation, I'm adding the token to Viewer Response as a cookie.

**The problem is, I can see the "set-cookie" header at client browser, but it doesn't set any cookies. Thus, the following requests doesn't include any cookie headers. I need to validate the token from cookie when there is no jwt in query string.**

**Viewer Request Code:**

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");

var response401 = {
    statusCode: 401,
    statusDescription: 'Unauthorized'
};

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const key = "SECRET KEY";
    const token = event.Records[0].cf.request.querystring.split("jwt=")[1];
  
    if(!token){
        console.log("Missing authorization token.");
        return response401;
    }
    
    try {
        jwt_decode(token,key)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return response401;
    }
    return request;
};


function jwt_decode(token, key, noVerify, algorithm) {
  // check token
  if (!token) {
    throw new Error("No token supplied");
  }
  // check segments
  var segments = token.split(".");
  if (segments.length !== 3) {
    throw new Error("Not enough or too many segments");
  }

  // All segment should be base64
  var headerSeg = segments[0];
  var payloadSeg = segments[1];
  var signatureSeg = segments[2];
  
  // base64 decode and parse JSON
  var header = JSON.parse(_base64urlDecode(headerSeg));
  var payload = JSON.parse(_base64urlDecode(payloadSeg));

  if (!noVerify) {
    var signingMethod = "sha256";
    var signingType = "hmac";

    // Verify signature. `sign` will return base64 string.
    var signingInput = [headerSeg, payloadSeg].join(".");

    if (!_verify(signingInput, key, signingMethod, signingType, signatureSeg)) {
      throw new Error("Signature verification failed");
    }

    // Support for nbf and exp claims.
    // According to the RFC, they should be in seconds.
    if (payload.nbf && Date.now() < payload.nbf * 1000) {
      throw new Error("Token not yet active");
    }

    if (payload.exp && Date.now() > payload.exp * 1000) {
      throw new Error("Token expired");
    }
  }

  return payload;
}

function _verify(input, key, method, type, signature) {
  if (type === "hmac") {
    console.log(signature, _sign(input, key, method));
    return signature === _sign(input, key, method);
  } else {
    throw new Error("Algorithm type not recognized");
  }
}

function _sign(input, key, method) {
  return crypto.createHmac(method, key).update(input).digest("base64url");
}

function _base64urlDecode(str) {
  return Buffer.from(str, "base64").toString("utf-8");
}
```

**And the Viewer Response Code**

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");

var response401 = {
    statusCode: 401,
    statusDescription: 'Unauthorized'
};

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

    try {
     
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    const token = event.Records[0].cf.request.querystring.split("jwt=")[1];
    const headers = response.headers;
   
    const headerNameSrc = 'X-Amz-Meta-Last-Modified';
    const headerNameDst = 'Last-Modified';

    if (headers[headerNameSrc.toLowerCase()]) {
        headers[headerNameDst.toLowerCase()] = [{
            key: headerNameDst,
            value: headers[headerNameSrc.toLowerCase()][0].value,
        }];
        console.log(`Response header "${headerNameDst}" was set to ` +
                    `"${headers[headerNameDst.toLowerCase()][0].value}"`);
    }
   
    const cookie = `token=${token}; Secure; HttpOnly; Max-Age=18000; SameSite=None`;
    response.headers['set-cookie'] = [{
      key : "set-cookie",
      value : cookie
    }];

    return response;
    } catch (error) {
         console.log(error);
        return response401;
    }
    
};
```

So, how can I solve the problem? Are there any missing CloudFront configuration?

Comment: If you see the set-cookie header at the client then what does the result look like? Is the cookie stored locally in the browser, with the correct configuration?

Comment: I can see the set-cookie header at response but I can't see any cookies in my browser. Looks like it is doesn't set any cookies.